# Pivot sql server multiple tables and columns

Tags: php, excel, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

it's my first time to come here. In generally i find myself some answers but now i got a big problem with PIVOT sql server 2012. I'm just an intern and i don't know how to do PIVOTS with Multiple Tables and Columns in using PHP.
So i Have 3 Tables (Equipements, Champ-perso, Equipement_Complément), I succeeded to display all the data through a SQL query using PHP. But in this display, There are equipements which are duplicate, and Champ-Perso and Equipement_Complément appear in rows. 
And I want to do a function PIVOT which deletes equipements duplicate, and displays Champ-Perso and Equipement_Complément in columns.

Here is my display

```
`Name_Equipement     Champ-Perso               Equipemennt-Complément

ENG-0001         Année rénovation                  A
ENG-0001         Largeur utile (mm)                B
ENG-0001         Nb de pinces de dépose            C
ENG-0001         Nb de postes dengagement          D
ENG-0001         Nb de voies                       E
ENG-0001         Numéro du train                   F
ENG-0001         Type/modèle                       G
ENG-0002         Année rénovation                  A1
ENG-0002         Largeur utile (mm)                B1
ENG-0002         Nb de pinces de dépose            C1
ENG-0002         Nb de postes dengagement          D1
ENG-0002         Nb de voies                       E1
ENG-0002         Numéro du train                   F1
ENG-0002         Type/modèle                       G1
`
```

And i want to display

```
`Name_Equipment Année rénovation Largeur Utile (mm) ... Type:Modèle            
ENG-0001         A                 B                ...   G
ENG-0002         A1                B1               ...   G1
`
```

Comment: if Champ_perso has n (variable) values, then you must use dynamic sql such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query.  If you know the champ-Perso will always be the same number (7 it appears in this case) then you can use a normal Pivot to do this.  You simply hard code the camp-perso values into the pivot. .  To help beyond this we would need to see the SQL, table structure.  The desired results helps, but isn't sufficient without the SQL or table structures

Comment: the table structures is required. However, would `select DISTINCT` be enough ?

Comment: Please can you tell me if my query is correct, cause in SQL server i got an error like " Impossible to add a table 'SELECT' ":                   SELECT EQUIPEMENTS.EQU_EQUIPEMENT, [EQU_COMPLEMENTS.EQC_VALEUR_A],[CHAMPS_PERSOS.CHP_DESIGNATION] 
FROM 
(My sql query) as src
PIVOT
(
FOR CHAMPS_PERSOS.CHP_DESIGNATION 
IN([Année rénovation], [Largeur utile (mm)], 
[Nb de pinces de dépose], [Nb de postes dengagement], 
[Nb de voies], 
[Numéro de train], 
[Type/modèle])
) as Pv1

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution for your problem. I assume that the data shown in your question is in table `#temp`.

First you need to find unique `Champ-Perso` from your table. Use below query.

```
select * into #temp1 from (select distinct([Champ-Perso]) from #temp) as A
```

Now write your pivot query as below...

```
Declare @str nvarchar(1000)
Declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)
SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str+'],[', '') + [Champ-Perso] FROM   #temp1
set @str = '[' +@str + ']'

set @SQL = N' select [Name_Equipement], ' + @str +' from (select [Name_Equipement], [Champ-Perso], [Equipemennt-Complément] from #temp) as tbl
Pivot
(
 max([Equipemennt-Complément])
 for [Champ-Perso] in ('+ @str+')
) as p'
```

To get the result, fire this query...

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

**Note:** Since `Champ-Perso` is not common across your `Name_Equipement`, so you will see `NULL` whereever the value would be missing.